# Where does Portainer save the yaml files?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, portainer

On Manjaro linux, I installed nextcloud using portainer.  Now I want to find the yaml file that portainer is using for my nextcloud container.  I want to make some edits to the yaml file.  I assume that portainer has generated one somewhere but I cannot find it anywhere.

To install nextcloud I simply pressed the "new container" button and filled in the relevant information.  Nextcloud then was installed and is working.  I have been using portainer to manage nextcloud but I would like to make a specific edit that I need access to the nextcloud yaml file to make.

Where are all my yaml files?

These were not helpful:
https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/3522
https://www.reddit.com/r/portainer/comments/xc58i8/noob_question_where_can_i_find_the/